# Firebase Request Timeout Feature

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Currently a client would send an http request to a Firebase http cloud function which returns immediately and set up a finite state machine in the Firebase realtime database. The client will listen to that database location to determine what to do next. I want to implement on the server side a timer of 3 minutes, or maybe 5, after which the server will change the finite state machine value from "waiting" to "timeout", thereby notifying the client of the timeout. (Think of a ride request on a mobile app timing out after getting no response from the drivers.)

However, currently the only way I can think of is to use setTimeout in javascript, hoping that it will keep executing after the http function returns with response.status(200). I'm confused that after the http function returns with 300ms execution time, the setTimeout still managed to change the value from "waiting" to "timeout" 3 minutes after the http function returned.

I'm wondering if this is a standard behavior that we can consistently expect? and also would setting a timeout value of 5 min for setTimeout incur any cost after the http function returns?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44313111/how-to-use-javascript-settimeout-function-in-firebase-cloud-functions

Comment: The linked answer describes how to use `setTimeout` in Cloud Functions. You will indeed be billed for the time you're waiting.

Comment: So if we wait for 3 minutes is the charge calculated solely based on the execution time? I can imagine that the CPU utilization is very low and so is the memory. Does the GB second rate apply here?