# how to use firebaes realtime database or firestore to make votes valid for only a certain time?

Tags: android, firebase

I was wondering what is the best way to send a vote say for example the initial value of the vote is 0 and someone sends a +1 (vote+=1) after a certain time like 20min that vote will be undone (vote-=1). Is there some functionality in firebase to do this? Because I want the undoing to work even though the user isn't using the android application. I thought about keeping a device always connected to the database and watch the changes but this doesn't look very stable. Is it possible to use a server? If firebase isn't the best option what should I look up online?

Comment: This is really broad, and hard to answer succinctly; not in the least because you indicate two separate databases as being totally fine. Since you're talking about server-side validation, I'd start by looking into server-side security rules. Try some things with it, and then post what you tried. That will make it both easier to understand what you're trying to accomplish, and increase the chances that someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

[cloud functions on read/right/updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?authuser=0) to firestore is down your alley. The biggest problem i see is that you would use setTimeout for 20 minutes and you would get billed alot. [Another forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44313111/how-to-use-javascript-settimeout-function-in-firebase-cloud-functions) with a similar problem recommends to run a cloud function every once in a while to purge old votes. I recommend on upvote push the date into an array and use length as the total number of votes, and every 10 minutes or whatever have a function run that looks if the dates are older than 20 minutes and deletes accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately the first suggestion won't work, as the [maximum timeout](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation) for a cloud function is only 9 minutes.  It is true that [scheduled functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) and logging all of the votes with their timestamp is a viable approach.